# error when Im using group by in select query

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select id, convert(nvarchar(10), pubdate, 102) as pubdate, 
  channel_title, title, description, link, vertinimas 
from table1
where statusid > 0
  and channel_title = 'channel1'
group by title
order by pubdate desc
```

to exclude duplicate entries in the field "title" i added group by title in the end, but an error occurs:
"is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: As the DBMS told you, you have to either add an aggregate function to every expression not listed in `group by` (if it is an attribute of `title`) or add the expression (or a columns used in the expression) to the `group by`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) Simplify! [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY clause can only be used with aggregate functions like count(), min(), max(), sum() etc. The select query can only select the columns which are part of GROUP BY clause or on which you are applying an aggregate function.

For example you have a STUDENT table like below:

| ID | NAME | SUBJECT | MARKS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FOO | ENGLISH | 80 |
| 2 | FOO | MATH | 70 |
| 3 | BAR | ENGLISH | 100 |
| 4 | BAR | MATH | 50 |
| 5 | ZIL | ENGLISH | 90 |
| 6 | ZIL | MATH | 75 |

you can write a query like:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(MARKS) AS TOTAL FROM STUDENT GROUP BY NAME;
```

Hear in the above query NAME is part of your GROUP BY clause and we are applying sum() aggregate function on column on MARKS. This will give us a result like below:

| NAME | MARKS |
| --- | --- |
| FOO | 150 |
| BAR | 150 |
| ZIL | 165 |

In your query above in the post, only title is part of GROUP BY column. Rest all the column like id, pubdate, channel_title, title, description, link, vertinimas, they are neither part of GROUP BY clause nor passed as a parameter in any aggregate function.

If you want to find / exclude / delete duplicate rows, you can checkout this blog post. This guy has explained it pretty well. Here is the like to [find and delete duplicate records](http://queryportal.blogspot.com/2013/12/find-and-delete-duplicate-records.html)!